# Epithet, Stylistic Device

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, metaphors

Can you please tell me whether in the following sentence *the naked light* is an epithet or not, thanks in advance.

> I lived by night and shunned the naked light of day.

Comment: What do you think an *epithet* is, and why do you think *the naked light* might be one?

Comment: Also, why was this question tagged with [tag:single-word-requests]? Are you asking for a word to describe it if it *isn't* an epithet?